# How to wait for a mySQL-query to complete in c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I am having an issue where I need to wait for a query to complete before I move on in my Program. But I cannot figure out how.

Here is a code snippet that should explain the circumstances:

```
//aggregate.h
class Aggregate
{
    public:
        Aggregate* duplicate();
        Aggregate(const char *id);
    private:
        const char *id;
        const char *name;
        const char *description;
};

//aggregate.cpp
Aggregate* Aggregate::duplicate()
{
    const char *newId = Helper::constructNewId();
    MYSQL *connection = Helper::getConnection();
    std::string query("INSERT INTO Aggregates (ID, name, description) SELECT '");
    query.append(newId);
    query.append("', name, description FROM Aggregates WHERE ID = '");
    query.append(this->id);
    query.append("'");

    mysql_query(connection, query.c_str());
    //Insert something to wait until the insert is completed
    mysql_close(connection);

    return new Aggregate(newId);
}

Aggregate::Aggregate(const char *id)
{
    MYSQL *connection = Helper::getConnection();
    std::string query("SELECT name, description FROM Aggregates WHERE ID = '");
    query.append(id);
    query.append("'");

    mysql_query(connection, query.c_str());
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    if (!(row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {
        //Here I am handling the Error that should not happen
        //because I inserted a row with that ID in the duplicate
        //and is successfully inserted as proofed via phpMyAdmin
    }

    this->id = id;
    this->name = row[0];
    this->description = row[1];

    mysql_query(connection, query.c_str());
    mysql_close(connection);
}
```

In this snippet I removed error handling and several other steps to prevent runtime errors which are not relevant to understand my issue. I also cannot say "I just inserted this copy so I could use the the copied objects members to initialize the copy." because my project manager wants it this way.

EDIT: modified code snipet

Comment: what makes you think that the call to `mysql_query` isn't synchronous?

Comment: the query in "new Aggregate(newId);" in the "duplicate" the row with the new inserted id is not found so I think the "INSERT INTO" is not completed at the time of the "SELECT FROM"

Comment: Are you sure that the passed `id` parameter generated by `Helper::constructNewId()` is in newly allocated heap memory, and not just a pointer to a static buffer that gets re-used every time the function is called?

Comment: having fixed your snippet, please show the error that you report occurs, because merely being unable to find a row is not an error, you just get an empty result set

Comment: Either way, I can assure you that `mysql_query` does *not* return until the data has been inserted into the database.

Comment: Yes. It does. As the name implies `Helper::constructNewId()` constructs an ID which is guaranteed to be unused and not be used again.

Comment: if `mysql_query` does not return before the INSERT is completed why is the SELECT returning an empty result?

Comment: I would try running you code in a debugger stopping on the `mysql_close(connection)` line of the `::duplicate` method and then querying the database interactively to check for the key.    You have no error checking on the `INSERT` statement so you've no way to check that it even succeeds.

Comment: As I stated "I removed error handling [...] which are not relevant to understand my issue" and I said that if I look into the database it is correctly inserted.

Comment: Do you use transactions for the database? Maybe you miss a "complete transaction" statement, so the insert is rolled-back?

Comment: The insert cannot not be rolled back. As stated in the question the row can be found in the database afterwards. So the "SELECT" in the constructore must be finished before the "INSERT" in `::duplicate`

Comment: still mystified by this, it really shouldn't be necessary to wait.  Can only additionally suggest putting `(void) mysql_store_result(connection);` before closing the connection in the `duplicate()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A senior of mine found the error to not be in that code snippet. It was caused by something I so far did not knew of. There was at first a constructor used as "conversion" constructor which it is not. The second error was that I had a wrong class in a function's signature.